# Error occurring when packing Ignite Client in jar and pack into war for deployment

Tags: ignite

Encountered the issue in the stacktrace below when i pack Ignite Client into jar and include inside a war file. This war file is then deployed into Weblogic.

However, when it is accessed through the war file, and accessed through web service, the above error occurred (Ignite Client is started within the jar included in the war file). Had tried using Java Serializable and Binarylizable but still encountering this issue. Having a feel that it is because of including inside a war file that cause the error but not sure whats the basis.

Any idea on this? Thanks in advance~

2017-08-30 15:43:26.064 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG - Sending: [msg=GridH2QueryRequest [reqId=1, caches=[1877462957], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersio
n [topVer=18, minorTopVer=0], parts=null, qryParts=null, pageSize=1024, qrys=[GridCacheSqlQuery [qry=SELECT
"AmVslData".__Z0._KEY __C0_0,
"AmVslData".__Z0._VAL __C0_1
FROM "AmVslData".AMVSLDATA __Z0
WHERE __Z0.VSLM = ?1, paramIdxs=[0], cols={__C0_0=GridSqlType [type=6, scale=32767, precision=65535, displaySize=65535, sql=DECIMAL(65535, 32767)], __C0_1=GridSqlType [type=19, scale=0, precision=2147483647,
 displaySize=2147483647, sql=OTHER]}, alias=null, sort=[], partitioned=true, node=null, derivedPartitions=null]], flags=2, tbls=null, timeout=0, params=[AM VESSEL], schemaName=AmVslData], nodes=[TcpDiscovery
Node [id=32a226c4-f989-4e69-8209-abf56486ab3b, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.115.44.3, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.115.44.3:47500, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrde
r=1, lastExchangeTime=1504078887589, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170721-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=false]], specialize=null]
2017-08-30 15:43:26.180 [query-#34%cluster-pcp%] DEBUG - Processed response: 32a226c4-f989-4e69-8209-abf56486ab3b->ae092c6f-4d5a-475c-98d1-87e9bcb4622c GridQueryNextPageResponse [qryReqId=1, segmentId=0, qry
=0, page=0, allRows=1, cols=2, retry=null, valsSize=2, rowsSize=0]
2017-08-30 15:43:26.364 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR - ERROR!!!: {}
org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: Requesting mapping from grid failed for [platformId=0, typeId=1331964677]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:695) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1755) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1714) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:797) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:143) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:161) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinariesIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:106) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinariesIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:51) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryCacheObjectsIterator.next(GridQueryCacheObjectsIterator.java:67) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryCacheObjectsIterator.next(GridQueryCacheObjectsIterator.java:31) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$9$1.next(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1210) ~[ignite-indexing-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$9$1.next(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1204) ~[ignite-indexing-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.query.IgniteRepositoryQuery.transformQueryCursor(IgniteRepositoryQuery.java:232) ~[ignite-spring-data-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.query.IgniteRepositoryQuery.execute(IgniteRepositoryQuery.java:119) ~[ignite-spring-data-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEAS
E.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3144.findByVslM(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.psa.pc.am.stw.component.AMServiceComponent.getSpaVesselProfileData(AMServiceComponent.java:55) ~[com.psa.pc.am.stw.component-0.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.psa.pc.am.stw.bizfunction.AMBusinessFunctionUtil.deriveVesselProfileData(AMBusinessFunctionUtil.java:183) [_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at com.psa.pc.am.stw.bizfunction.AMBusinessFunction.lambda$null$2(AMBusinessFunction.java:122) [_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at com.psa.pc.cs.ac.bizfn.Orchestrator.execute(Orchestrator.java:26) ~[com.psa.pc.cs.ac-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
        at com.psa.pc.am.stw.bizfunction.AMBusinessFunction.lambda$getSpaVesselProfileData$3(AMBusinessFunction.java:124) [_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at com.psa.pc.cs.rest.RestWSResponseUtil.perform(RestWSResponseUtil.java:55) ~[com.psa.pc.cs.rest-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
        at com.psa.pc.cs.rest.RestWSResponseUtil.perform(RestWSResponseUtil.java:47) ~[com.psa.pc.cs.rest-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
        at com.psa.pc.am.stw.bizfunction.AMBusinessFunction.getSpaVesselProfileData(AMBusinessFunction.java:103) [_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) ~[javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.psa.appfw.security.filter.SecurityAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityAuthFilter.java:76) ~[com.psa.appfw.security.filter-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
:
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348) ~[com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333) ~[com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.work.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Requesting mapping from grid failed for [platformId=0, typeId=1331964677]
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:383) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:342) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:686) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        ... 126 common frames omitted

Comment: As per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm ,  we would need more information about the configuration of your WebLogic. Can you turn classloading logging on and show if anything interesting appears there? Is filtering classloading enabled?

Comment: Manage to get it working with BinaryConfiguration. Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get it working with the following configuration

```
BinaryConfiguration binaryCfg = new BinaryConfiguration();
binaryCfg.setIdMapper(new BinaryBasicIdMapper());
binaryCfg.setNameMapper(new BinaryBasicNameMapper(true));
binaryCfg.setTypeConfigurations(Arrays.asList(
    new BinaryTypeConfiguration().setTypeName(AmVslData.class.getName()))
);
cfg.setBinaryConfiguration(binaryCfg);
```